# Python, AttributeError with no 'isclass' when importing pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

Pandas used to work well on my computer. But today suddenly it pops an error message, when I try to import it in a script (Version pip upgrade.py):

```
import pandas as pd
print pd.__version__
```

It pops:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'isclass'
```

I tried uninstalled, reinstall an updated version of Pandas.

I googled and tried some other changes. It said the problem relates to NLTK so I uninstall NLTK but the problem persists. I also tried to change the Environment Variable but no help.

What went wrong and how can I correct it?

Thank you.

here is the whole error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Working Scripts\Version pip upgrade.py", line 1, in <module>
import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    import inspect
  File "C:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "C:\Python27\Working Scripts\tokenize.py", line 3, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 115, in     <module>
    from nltk.decorators import decorator, memoize
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\decorators.py", line 187, in     <module>
    @decorator
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\decorators.py", line 165, in decorator
    if inspect.isclass(caller):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'isclass'
```

Comment: Looks like `inspect` module is not what it is supposed to be. Maybe you are shadowing it somewhere? Could you provide all code in `Version pip upgrade.py`?

Comment: @KamilNiski, thank you for the comment. the Version pip upgrade.py is actually to import and check the version of Pandas only. I added it to the question. Please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: I think that you are shadowing `tokenize` module with `C:\Python27\Working Scripts\tokenize.py`. Could you try and change its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are shadowing `tokenize` module with `C:\Python27\Working Scripts\tokenize.py`. Could you try and change its name?

Internally `inspect` imports python builtin module `tokenize` but it appears that you have `tokenize.py` next to script you try to run.

Python will search for modules to import in current directory first. And in your case it finds one where in reality it requires the one of python builtin modules.

Comment: superb! that's exactly the problem! thank you! I remove the tokenize.py also tokenize.pyc. Pandas version 0.23.4 pops more error message. I restarted computer and uninstalled it. Reinstalled pandas version 0.20.3 and now works fine.